# How do I subset a vector while retaining row names?

Tags: r, matrix, subset, logical-operators

I am looking for differentially expressed genes in a data set. After using my function to determine fold change, I am given a vector that returns the gene names and fold change which looks like this:

```
df1
               [,1]
gene1074  1.1135131
gene22491 1.0668137
gene15416 0.9840414
gene18645 1.1101060
gene4068  1.0055899
gene19043 1.1463878
```

I want to look for anything that has a greater than 2 fold change, so to do this I execute:

```
df2 <- subset(df1 >= 2)
```

which returns the following:

```
head(df2)
           [,1]
gene1074  FALSE
gene22491 FALSE
gene15416 FALSE
gene18645 FALSE
gene4068  FALSE
gene19043 FALSE
```

and that is not what I'm looking for.

I've tried another subsetting method:

```
df2 <- df1[df1 >= 2]
```

which returns:

```
head(df2)
[1]   4.191129 127.309557   2.788121   2.090916  11.382345   2.186330
```

Now that is the values that are over 2, but I've lost the gene names that came along with them.

How would I go about subsetting my data so that it returns in the following format:

```
head(df2)
          [,1]
genex   4.191129
geney   127.309557 
genez   2.788121
genea   2.090916
geneb   11.382345
```

Or something at least approximating that format where I am given the gene and it's corresponding fold change value

Comment: Try `df1[df1 >= 2, , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: good practice is to share data with dput(). What you are sharing looks like a matrix, not vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for subsetting like so:

```
df2 <- df1[df1[, 1] >= 2, ]
```

To show you on some data:

```
# Create some toy data
df1 <- data.frame(val = rexp(100))
rownames(df1) <- paste0("gene", 1:100)
head(df1)
#            val
#gene1 0.9295632
#gene2 1.2090513
#gene3 0.1550578
#gene4 1.7934942
#gene5 0.7286462
#gene6 1.8424025
```

Now we take the first column of `df1` and compare to 2 (`df1[,1] > 2`). The output of that (a logical vector) is used to select the rows which fulfill the criteria:

```
df2 <- df1[df1[,1] > 2, ]
head(df2)
#[1] 2.705683 3.410672 3.544905 3.695313 2.523586 2.229879
```

Using the `drop = FALSE` keeps the output as a `data.frame`:

```
df3 <- df1[df1[,1] > 2, ,drop = FALSE]
head(df3)
#            val
#gene8  2.705683
#gene9  3.410672
#gene22 3.544905
#gene23 3.695313
#gene38 2.523586
#gene42 2.229879
```

The same can be achieved by

```
subset(df1, subset = val > 2)
```

or

```
subset(df1, subset = df1[1,] > 2)
```

The former of these two expressions does not work in your case as it appears you have not named the columns.

Comment: I added a name for the column and both of those last two options worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also compute the positions in the data that correspond to your predicate, and use them for indexing:

```
# create some test data
df <- read.csv(
  textConnection(
    "g, v
    gene1074, 1.1135131
    gene22491, 1.0668137
    gene15416, 0.9840414
    gene18645, 1.1101060
    gene4068, 1.0055899
    gene19043, 1.1463878"
  ))

# positions that match a given predicate
idx <- which(df$v > 1)

# indexing "as usual"
df[idx, ]
```

Output:

```
              g        v
1      gene1074 1.113513
2     gene22491 1.066814
4     gene18645 1.110106
5      gene4068 1.005590
6     gene19043 1.146388
```

I find this code reads quite nicely and is pretty intuitive, but that might just be my opinion.